# Rails model structure for users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails, and I'm working on my second rails app.

The app will have different roles for users, but some users will have multiple roles.

Every user of the site will be an Artist. Some users will have the role of a moderator.

How would I structure this? In some PHP apps I've used, there is only one user, and then a database column for is_admin, etc. But I've looked at the source for rails apps and have seen separate models for User and Admin, etc. although I'm not sure why.

So, should I have a single User model with a role attribute, which could be Moderator, and then just call Users "Artists" in my views, routes, etc.?

Or should I have a User model, a Moderator model which inherits from it, and an Artist model which belongs_to User?

I'm really confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look for gems Devise and CanCan. This pair is really powerful combination. This makes two models User and Role. In Role you can create new roles, without creating new models for them. Although it creates model Ability, here you can define access rules for roles.

Manual:
http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/

Here you can find Devise's and CanCan's sources and wikies:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

My models looks like this:

Role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role_ids

  def role?(role)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
  end

end
```

Ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role? :administrator
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? :operator
      can :read, Account
      can :read, Server
    elsif user.role? :customer
      can :manage, Account
      can :read, Server
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller you must add only this two lines:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  ...

end
```

Comment: This would have been my suggestion.  What I like about this approach is that it encourages separation of business policy from the rest of your application logic.

Comment: Yes this separation gives good and flexible abilities. I'm used it in the one project, where developers made very uncomfortable authentication system, where for adding new roles and abilities I had to write a lot of code in each controller and model. I'm spent a lot of time for removing old system and near two hours for installing and configuring Devise and CanCan. Now I'm happy. And when I'm will have free time I'm planning to write user interface for manage roles and abilities. With these systems this task has become simply.

Comment: we've used this in several applications and we also find the devise-cancan mix to be the 'best-of-breeds' approach.  It's rapidly being adopted by many orgs as this years standard for authentication/authorization.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have to create different models because you don't have specific fields for each one. So you just have to set the "role" of each User. Two options : create a role table or add a role field in the table User. Both solutions work, the second is more flexible but less optimized.

But, in your particular case, you don't have a complex role management so you can find a simpler solution. If all of your users are artists you don't have to specify this in your code, it's contained in the implicit description of what a user is. So you just have to save if a user is an admin or not and I think the best solution is to create a boolean field "is_admin".

After that you will have to create some before_filter in your protected controllers, like that :

```
before_filter => :authorize, :only => :new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy

def authorize
  redirect_to :root if not current_user.is_admin?
end
```

And you can have simple requests like that :

```
@artists = User.all
@moderators = User.where(:is_admin => true)
```

If you look for a more complete authorization system you can check this small gem : https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

But I think it's not the case for the moment. If you have a simple problem look for a simple solution !

Comment: Boolean values in AR produce `foo?` methods that are great for conditionals, and Ruby has a better `if not` in the form of `unless`. Combining those together: `redirect_to :root unless current_user.is_admin?`

Comment: +1 for simple solutions. The nice thing about ruby is that you can use the boolean field and keep the `is_admin?` interface when you change to a separate role model or something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have code that's specific to and role or such as an admin or moderator one other solution would be to create a base User model that all the other classes inherit from. You can then create an Admin class and a Moderator class that inherit from the User model. This would mean you can avoid constantly checking the users role in your code e.g. `current_user.do_some_admin_thing if current_user.is_admin?`. Your classes would look something like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # base user methods in here
end

class Moderator < User
  def do_moderator_thing
    # perform a moderator task
  end
end

class Admin < Moderator
  def do_admin_thing
    # perform an admin task
  end
end
```

In this instance the User class has the most basic privileges, moderators can do everything users can plus the moderator specific methods and admins can do everything users and moderators can plus the admin specific methods.

All the different user roles would use the same table in the database but your concerns are neatly separated into classes which avoids excessive conditionals through your code checking what role the user is all the time.

Creating new users would be straightforward also `Admin.new :name => 'bob'` the Admin class then takes care of how a user is defined as an admin which provides a nice interface where you don't need to know the inner workings of the role system to interact with users.

Comment: Please edit your question to be explicit about the fact that this is using Single Table Inheritance and link to the official rails documentation on it.

Comment: The question doesn't talk about different behavior for different users, just different authorization to do different things.  Unless instance of User models actually behave differently, it's overly complex to create different subclasses.  Overuse of inheritance is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree the combination of Devise and CanCan is powerful and works. Let us look at it with a different perspective keeping Association and Delegation in mind.

> **Association:** In object-oriented programming, association defines a
>   relationship between classes of objects that allows one object
>   instance to cause another to perform an action on its behalf.
>
> **Delegation:** Delegation allows the behaviour of an object to be
>   defined in terms of the behaviour of another object.  The term
>   'delegation' refers to the delegation of responsibility. The primary
>   emphasis of delegation is on message passing where an object could
>   delegate responsibility of a message it couldn't handle to objects
>   that potentially could (its delegates).

With that, what if we design our User and Roles like this. There is no Role class and the User doesn't inherit or specialise a particular class ( Artist, Admin ) instead, all the (Role) class contain the User object and delegate. The way I am thinking and way to implement with Rails is something like this:

```
class User < AR::Base
  def user_method
  end
end 

class Artist < AR::Base
  has_one :user

  def artist_method
    # perform an admin task
  end
end

class Admin < AR::Base
  has_one :user

  def admin_method
    # perform an admin task
  end
end
```

This [role class model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role_Class_Model) is described by Francis G. Mossé in his article on Modelling Roles.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic setup, for the [declarative authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) gem, I use. But you could just use this as is without the gem, if your authorization requirements aren't more than asking the kind of Roles the User has.

It does require a `roles` table, and such, so that might not really be your fancy.

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles

  def role_symbols
    roles.map { |r| r.title.to_sym }
  end

  def admin?
    has_role?(:admin)
  end
  # include more role booleans or write some ruby magic to be DRY
  # ...

  def has_role?(r)
    role_symbols.include?(r.to_sym)
  end
end

# give or take
user = User.new
user.roles << Role.new :title => "admin"
user.roles << Role.new :title => "artist"

user.role_symbols # => [:admin, :artist]
user.admin? # => true
user.has_role?(:artist) # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two models User and Role. And Role belongs to User.

Specify role of users (like admin, moderator) in Role model.