# Giving admin different fields to edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My app has Users and it has Chefs.  A user can be a chef and a chef can be a user.  Chefs have the ability to create meals, and get paid for there meals, users do not have this ability.  A user can become a chef if they request and are approved.

The plan is to have one User model with a boolean field for being a chef.  If the chef field is true, the chef will have more functionality than the normal user, such as creating a meal and getting paid for the meal.  Where I am confused is how I structure the models so that only a chef can create a meal.

Do I create roles?  Such as the post below is suggesting, or do I create two separate models one for Chefs and one for Users.  My thought is that I have only one model so people do not have to sign up for two different accounts.

[Rails model structure for users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292898/rails-model-structure-for-users), or is there another alternative.

Thoughts/Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest checking out [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) which will allow you to run permissions based on settings for a given user.  For example, if you want to allow a `User` with a property `chef` set to true, you could set up your `MealPolicy#create` to check for `user.chef?`